# Firebase: Is it possible to stream a video?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I searched about this issue, but didn't find a clear answer or any way to implement this.

If I have a video in firebase cloud storage is it possible to stream it (like youtube), in which you can see the progress as it download stream and in which you can see the progress as the video plays.

Any ideas?

Thanks.